# Giving a string a null value

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, nullable

I am in need of some information on how I can set this string in the code snippet below to a `null` value.

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[StringLength(450)]
public string StockCode
{
    get { return _stockCode; }
    set { _stockCode = value.ToUpper(); } //(ToUpper)<<-- Error
}
```

When I try to do it the normal way `public string? StockCode` I get the error at my `.ToUpper` and it says:

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpper'
>   and no extension method 'ToUpper' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I am no expert or pro C# coder, so I have no clue how to set my string to a null value and still use `.ToUpper` in the way I am trying to do it. :( Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: remove the `?` from `string`

Comment: You can't have nullable strings, `string?` will not compile.

Comment: There is no reason to have a nullable string, because a string is a nullable object on it's own.  The Nullable wrapper should only be used for primitive and value types.

Comment: Just an FYI -- if your string is null, you can't call a method on it as a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown.  By default, all strings are null unless set otherwise (actually all reference types are null by default).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you want to face all the complications when you will try to get this property but simply adding a check for the null value before applying  ToUpper()

```
set { _stockCode = (value == null ? null : value.ToUpper()); }
```

Comment: Or for the faint of heart a simple `if` :-)

Comment: @xanatos what are you, crazy?!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use nullable type on string. String by default accepts null values and can be checked by `string.IsNullOrEmpty(StockCode);`

Comment: I downvoted you because a string cannot be a nullable as it's not a value type; it's an object / reference type.  Only value types can be nullable and therefore the .HasValue() method is not valid.  However, the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` is a good suggestion for OP